# Center Image using Flutter onboarding Slider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to centre an image when using this flutter onboarding slider however the image will only centre left. I've attached a link to the pub.dev library and the git repo.

I am using the example code available in the pub.dev however having no luck

pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen
gitHub: https://github.com/appinioGmbH/flutter_packages

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you share your code, please?

Comment: Hi @twinsinc - I am using the example code from this link - https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen/example